# Why don't connect android to database directly?

Tags: android, mysql, sql, sql-server, security

I see many people trying to connect an Android device directly in a database like SQL Server or MySql and the answers are always the same: Use a web service. Why not connect directly an Android device with a database? I'm using a local network with my Android application.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a number of reasons.

1. Security- If the user has direct access, they can get anything from your database. Plus they will have a password into your database. As a result, if the SQL server you are using has a flaw, then they can exploit it. Also, if your permissions are set up wrong, the could wipe your database.
2. Speed- If the users frequently use large queries, then it can bog down your system quickly and needlessly. If you go through a web interface, you can throttle it.
3. Accessibility- Web queries are supported by almost everything. It requires special clients to access SQL databases directly.

But if you trust your users completely, have the right libraries/drivers, then you could allow direct querying, and it might even be a bit quicker.

Comment: Also increase memory size in phohe , is we saved database in mobile

Comment: The real question for me is: Isn't it same with the, for example a C# application running on Windows. It's better to use web services, instead of using direct connections because of absolutely same reasons. But it shouldn't be, there must be some difference. As a software developer which is using direct connection, either I'm doing it wrong or there is a difference which I didn't notice yet.

Answer (score 4):

If your app connects directly to the database server you have to hardcode username / password which is very insecure. With some tools an attacker can decompile your apk and can access username / password in this way and can connect to your database with read (+write) access without using your app.

Answer (score 1):

**Another reason not to access database directly**

**Problem** If you changed database architecture.
you have two solutions.

1- in direct access you will need to update every Client app
 2- using service you only need to upgrading the service.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the connection

You're not sure how many time you'll have to maintain this connection, if it's stable and if you're not going to lost it

Secondly, web-service are optimized to retrieve an information and serve it beautifully with standarts. You can also cache the informations to spare your DB