# Android app with SQL and webservice approach

Tags: android, sql, web-services

I am developing my first Android app which displays events in my city for the following days.
I am parsing the websites with PHP, then I am going to send these data to my database and user will fetch the events from it.

The very first problem I ran into is where to store my database. I am trying to figure out some better solution than using a server because there are just two tables. Is there any other simplier way than paying for the server?

Another thing is connecting the database with Android. I did some research and setting up the web service with REST api seems like the right way to go. Also I am thinking about Phonegap framework so that the app would work on iPhone and other devices.
Is this the right approach?

The last thing is storing the data on the Android side so that the app could work offline. I am thinking about creating SQLite database and on startup just to handle some queries or storing JSON file and parsing it. What's better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few pointers.

1. Use SQLlite for your database if it isn't large.
2. Don't directly query the database from the android app. Query a website which will return the results. Never allow external SQL connections. For reasons why, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13471874/544198).
3. Android supports SQLite as well, as you mentioned. The database is probably the best solution, unless you only have very small amounts of data (Parsing with JSON would take time.)

Comment: 1. now I see that SQLite is serverless so it is enough just to find a hosting which supports SQLite and PHP?

2. this topic and your answer there is reason why I have chosen REST web service:) Also I have seen some recommendations on JSON file format more than XML, is it easier to parse on Android side or why is that?
thank you

Comment: JSON is more compact than XML, but either one would work. JSON is typically sent as a response from a server.